# Programming language structure that can be recombined (for AI)?

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, element

I am trying to find out if what I am looking for exists. 
Basically, I am looking for a programming language where I can randomly recombine it's elements.
As an example, I could imagine a XML structure like the following, saying if foo=5 then bar=2:

```
<if>
  <parameter value="foo"/>
  <comparison type="equals">
    <int>5</int>
  </comparison>
  <then>
    <parameter value="bar"/>
    <comparison type="equals">
      <int>2</int>
    </comparison>
  <then>
</if>
```

Now I would like to randomly change elements of that structure. Not only 5 or 2, but the "equals" parameter, the values, perhaps nest even more if/then conditions in.

As far as I can see, to make this work I would need some sort of interpreter and a predefined set of input values and output actions, and probably a lot more.

Does something like that exist already? Doing this on my own seems like a huge task to me.

What do I need this for? I have a little sandbox of AI bots and would like to randomly modify their  AI code.

Comment: Lisp is a language where the source and data are made from the same types of things.

Comment: I know of no language designed to do that, but the idea has been had before.  Start with Koza's work on genetic programming where he uses tree structures, and maybe you'll find someone has developed a tool that you could use.

Comment: Thank you both, I found Koza and read a bit about Lisp. I think it should be possible to shuffle Lisp source parts around for different outcomes.

Comment: You might want to look at Prolog also.